# Is there an easy way to detect how many `C-u`s a command was given?

Tags: prefix-argument

I have made the following function to count how many `C-u` prefixes a command was given (assuming it is called interactively), but I feel this is a common-enough problem that there should be a built-in function (or a package that solves this problem more robustly).  Is there a better way to do this?

```
(defun tmp:how-many (arg)
  ;; Return zero if `arg' is 1 or nil
  (if (or (null arg) (equal arg 1)) 0
    ;; If `arg' is a list (as it is when called interactively), extract
    ;; the number.
    (when (listp arg)
      (setq arg (car arg)))
    ;; Recurse
    (if arg
        (1+ (tmp:how-many (/ arg 4)))
      0)))

(defun tmp:test (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (message "%S" (tmp:how-many arg)))
```

Comment: I simply [use a cl-case statement](https://github.com/kaushalmodi/.emacs.d/blob/master/setup-files/setup-windows-buffers.el#L173-195) of 4,16,64,.., t. In absence of prefix, the 't' case will be evaluated.

Comment: If you are asking about practical uses then I think it makes little sense to look for handling an arbitrary number of `C-u`s. If you are expecting users to use more than, say, five `C-u`s then you are probably really stretching it.  In practice, from zero to three is plenty. And in any case you need to distinguish the cases, whether you test 1, 2, 3 or 4, 16, 64.

Comment: @Drew Absolutely agree on all counts.  As with a lot of my questions (here and elsewhere), this one arises from sheer curiosity – not necessarily any overtly practical application. Still, I think the answers below are generally useful :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that you want to distinguish only uses of a plain prefix arg, e.g., `C-u`, `C-u C-u`, `C-u C-u C-u`, etc., and not uses of a numeric prefix arg, e.g., `C-u 23`, `C-9`, `C-- 5`.

Test both, in order:

1. Whether the value of `current-prefix-arg` is a cons, using `consp`.  If not, then a plain prefix arg was not used.
2. The `prefix-numeric-value` of `current-prefix-arg`, to see which power of 4 it is.

For example:

```el
(if (consp current-prefix-arg)
    (case (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg)
      (4   (do-C-u-stuff))
      (16  (do-C-u-C-u-stuff))
      (64  (do-C-u-C-u-C-u-stuff))
      ...)
  ...) ; Do something for absent prefix arg or non-plain prefix arg
```

`case` is a macro from the CL libraries.  Use `(eval-when-compile '(require 'cl))`.  (Or you can use `cl-case`, if your Emacs version has it.)

Comment: Is there an alternative for `case` from `cl-lib`?

Comment: Yes, `cl-case` is the same thing.

Comment: @Sean The hyperlink in my comment to your question takes you to an example of `cl-case` use.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it more fully addresses how one would handle prefix args, but I think it should be used in conjunction with my logarithm trick for clarity of code :) thanks!

Comment: Note that an absent prefix argument (`nil`) is returned as `1` by `prefix-argument-numeric-value`

Comment: Yes, of course `prefix-argument-numeric-value` returns 1 for `nil` `current-prefix-arg`. (But the only place that function is used here is for `consp` raw prefix args.)

Comment: @Drew your comment would imply otherwise ("Do something for absent prefix arg or non-plain prefix arg") but perhaps that isn't what you meant :)  While `nil` doesn't satisfy `consp`, it is still a valid prefix argument (in the sense that it is the sheer lack of one).  I'm not saying your code would break in any case :)

Comment: Huh? One reason `(consp ...)` can return `nil` is that no prefix arg was provided. In that case, the second `if` branch is taken, just as it is taken if a numeric (non-cons) prefix arg is provided.

Comment: I guess I had an extra paren after the `case`. I've removed that now.  That was probably what was confusing you.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you *only* want to understand arguments given using *only* `C-u`, you can use a base-four logarithm:

```
(defun tmp:how-many (arg)
  (when (consp arg)
    (truncate
     (log (car arg) 4))))
```

Note that such a function is doomed to fail if a sequence like `C-3 M-x tmp:test` is used; the only appropriate response to such usage is to signal an error or return `nil`, which was what I do here.  (Returning `arg` would imply ambiguous results between, e.g., `C-3 M-x tmp:test` and `C-u C-u C-u M-x tmp:test`.)

Comment: +1 for a logarithm with base 4!  I wish I could give a +2 for extreme cleverness.  Only minor suggestion would be to wrap the `log` in a `truncate`, since `log` returns a float and you probably want an integer.

Comment: @Dan ah, yes! Good idea :)